# Improving WP_Query performance for multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, performance, sql, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a site with several custom taxonomies, and have found that one of the slowest parts of the site is attempting to query with an OR across several of these at once. I'm using a `WP_Query` like so:

```
array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array('taxonomy' => 'tax1', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'term1'),
    array('taxonomy' => 'tax2', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'term2'),
    array('taxonomy' => 'tax3', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'term3'),
    array('taxonomy' => 'tax4', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'term4'),
  )
)
```

The SQL it generates takes an unacceptable 6 seconds to run:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt2.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt3.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (70) 
AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (23) 
  OR tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (5)
  OR tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (11)
  OR tt3.term_taxonomy_id IN (10) ) 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 500
```

But this equivalent query takes a much nicer 0.29 seconds:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (70)
AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (23, 5, 11, 10)) 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 500
```

Clearly the multiple joins are making it slower than it needs to be. The SQL doesn't care that the terms come from different taxonomies, but `WP_Query` does because they're looked up by slug. Is there any way to persuade `WP_Query` to generate something closer to the second one?

(Note the above has been anonymised to protect my client)

Comment: I started a core ticket on this issue: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18105

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure the AND case is equivalent?

Comment: Nope. Just seems right. I haven't made a patch and tested it yet, so not sure about anything, of course.

Comment: It seems like the OR case is equivalent with a single join because only one of the terms has to match. For the AND case, all the terms have to match so they really are separate parameters, each of which needs a separate join.

Comment: Also, the joins can only be merged if they're all IN queries. You can't merge an IN with a NOT IN join.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, but it's a really ugly one. I'd love to hear a better one, but I'm not sure it's possible.

`WP_Query::get_posts()` calls `parse_tax_query()` twice: first near the start, then again just before getting the SQL from it. There's no single hook that lets me intercept and adjust the value of `$tax_query` in time to adjust the SQL, so instead I had to do it in two parts.

- An action on `pre_get_posts`, near the start of `get_posts()` recognises taxonomy queries with `'relation' => 'OR'` and simplifies them so that they'll only generate one join on `wp_term_relationships`. At the same time it stores the resolved list of IDs from all the taxonomies inside the 'WP_Query' object to use later.
- A filter on `posts_where_paged`, much later in `query_posts()`, checks for a saved list of IDs and replaces the condition on the join.

Here's the code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wp_query__pre');
function wp_query__pre ($wp_query) {
  if (!isset($wp_query->query['tax_query'])) return;
  if ($wp_query->query['tax_query']['relation'] != 'OR') return;

  $allterms = array();
  foreach ($wp_query->tax_query->queries as $query) {
    $tax = $query['taxonomy'];
    $terms = $query['terms'];
    $wp_query->tax_query->_transform_terms($terms, $query['taxonomy'], $query['field'], 'term_taxonomy_id');
    $allterms = array_merge($allterms, $terms);
  }

  $tax_query = array(array(
      'taxonomy' => $tax,
      'terms' => $terms,
      'operator' => 'IN',
      'include_children' => 0,
      'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
    ));

  $wp_query->query['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
  $wp_query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
  $wp_query->tax_query = new WP_Tax_Query($tax_query);
  $wp_query->saved_tax_terms = $allterms;
}

add_filter('posts_where_paged', 'wp_query__where', 10, 2);
function wp_query__where ($where, $wp_query) {
  if (!empty($wp_query->saved_tax_terms)) {
    $terms = implode(", ", $wp_query->dft_tax_terms);
    $where = preg_replace("!term_taxonomy_id IN \([^)]*\)!", "term_taxonomy_id IN ($terms)", $where);
  }
  return $where;
}
```

Note that the code hasn't been tested thoroughly yet, and no doubt contains all manner of bugs. I probably won't cope with any more complicated queries.

The upside of this approach is that it doesn't require the rest of your code to know anything about it. Just code a taxonomy query with `OR` and it'll get picked up and optimised. It didn't provide quite as big a speed boost as I was hoping, but it was a definite improvement.

I'm wondering if the WordPress team shouldn't include something like this in the core code.

---

**Update:** As befits such an ugly hack, this is broken on WordPress 3.2. I'm looking into a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Wordpress use your more efficent query by using the posts_join and posts_where filter, something along the lines of:

```
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'tax_posts_join', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'tax_posts_where', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'tax_posts_request' );

function tax_posts_join( $sql, $wp_query ){
    if( $tax_ids = $wp_query->get('term_taxonomy_ids_in') )
        $sql .= " INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id )";

    return $sql;
}

function tax_posts_where( $sql, $wp_query ){
    if( $tax_ids = $wp_query->get('term_taxonomy_ids_in') ){
        $tax_ids = implode( ', ', $tax_ids );
        $sql .= " AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (".$tax_ids.") ) ";
    }   

    return $sql;
}

function tax_posts_request( $sql ){
    //var_dump( $sql );
    return $sql;
}


$args = array(
    'term_taxonomy_ids_in' => array(23, 5, 11, 10)
);

$tax_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That can be cleaned up a bit, probably sanitize the taxonomy ids before you make the sql, you might need the `posts_groupby` filter as well, but should get you going in the right direction.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries